# Using a variable in a function in Excel macros

Tags: excel, vba, function

This should be easy but as a newbie it has me stumped.  I am trying to go through a spreadsheet and delete the rows that do not contain specific text in column J.  The source data changes each month so I have to determine the last row every time I run the macro.
I can't get the Range function to accept the end point as a variable.   When trying to clear a row of data that I don't want I also get an error on the variable.  What is the proper syntax to use a variable in these functions?
The code I have tried is:

```
RowNum = RowCount

GroupCell = ("J" & RowNum)

For Each cell In Range("J2:("J" & RowNum)")  <-- doesn't work

For Each cell In Range("J2:GroupCell")       <-- doesn't work

For Each cell In Range("j2:j1756")   <--WORKS!

 RowNum = RowNum + 1

 
        If InStr(cell.Value, "Data that I want") > 0 Then

            MsgBox "Keep" & " " & RowNum


        Else

            Rows("RowNum:RowNum").Clear      <--- Doesn't work
       
        End If


    Next cell
```

Comment: Try `Range("J2:J" & RowNum )`

Comment: In VBA, variables belong outside quotes, and can be concatenated with `&`. So `For Each cell In Range("J2:" & GroupCell)` would work

Comment: Same with `Rows(RowNum & ":" & RowNum).Clear`

Comment: Perfect.  All suggestions worked!  Thank-you everyone.